# Сохранение View фрагмента

Tags: android

Есть `Фрагмент А`, у которого динамически формируется его представление. Этот фрагмент в процессе работы может быть временно заменен `Фрагментом Б`. Можно ли каким либо образом целиком сохранить `Фрагмент А` и его представление вместо повторного создания фрагмента и его представления при возвращении к нему? Весь смысл этого состоит в том, что бы сохранить динамически созданное представление `Фрагмента A` до момента его возвращения на экран.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, возможно.

Например, переход от фрагмента А к фрагменту Б можно осуществить не через метод `replace(...)` класса `FragmentTransaction`, а путем добавления `add(...)` фрагмента Б с последующим скрытием (`hide()`) фрагмента А и отображением `show()` фрагмента Б. А переход от фрагмента Б к фрагменту А сделать так же через `hide()/show()`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь все работает.